# iPhone Parse jQuery Mobile Page Table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, jquery-mobile

I want to parse data from a jQuery Mobile framework page into an UITableView.

Let's say there is a table on this specific page, I want to retrieve the data of this table.

How can I parse jQuery-mobile web pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more information? Do you want to translate a jquery-mobile listview to something rendered natively in an iOS app?

Comment: I want to "translate" an jQuery-mobile table to UITableView
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to translate your code to have something more native, I have the following solution:

You can use your UITableView with custom cells, in which you can set some `TTStyledTextLabel` from Three20 framework.

If you really want to do on-the-fly conversion of your page in cells, then you will have to parse the document by hand and get the data you need before setting the UITableView.

Comment: Thanks, I do want to parse the page and extract only the data I need

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest (but a bit longer) and more reliable option is to create another hidden page in your server wich feeds the same data in XML. Then you download it in the iPhone, parse it and use it for the UITable.

As I said, it's a bit more work because you have to make some code to generate the XML (wich should be very straightforward), but you'll end up with a more simple system to feed the data.

Comment: Thanks, good idea but the page I'm trying to parse is not on my server, I can only request the data using http

Comment: Ok, then do you have (and can you share) the webpage to see the code?

Comment: Yes, Thanks....
http://www.webtop.co.il/mobile/superSchool.aspx?view=timetable&fromView=timetable&autoLoad=8&schoolID=718&institutionCode=570036

Comment: you got yourself some complex code. From what I saw the jQuery mobile part is not relevant here, you have to parse regular HTML from the HTML Document and just ignore all the javaScript.

Comment: Maybe you could have a little web app in a server of yours wich parses the data of the given webpage and transforms it into XML. Your iPhone app talks to www.guydor.com/weirdpage, wich takes the HTML from web top.co.. and transforms it into an easier to parse XML/JSON wich is sent as a response to the iPhone. Then you use a simple parser to populate the UITableView. I think, at some additional programming an economic cost, will reduce the iPhone's processing and give you lot less headaches. Just get all the HTML, trim the JS, the spans, the imgs, and focus on the main table.